# Getting exception while running UPDATE JPA query for oracle data base through spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I'm using the below jpa query to update the records in to oracle data base. But getting the below error.

Jpa query:

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = "update NUMBER_POOL NP set NP.STATUS=:status , NP.CHANGE_DATE=:date where NP.RANGE_ID=:id and NP.STATUS= 15 LIMIT :limit ",nativeQuery = true)
    int approveMsisdnRange(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("status") Integer status, @Param("date") Date date,@Param("limit") int limit);
```

---

error

> 2023-10-14 10:30:44.779  WARN 17204 --- [         task-2]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 933, SQLState:
> 42000 2023-10-14 10:30:44.779 ERROR 17204 --- [         task-2]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00933: SQL command not
> properly ended
>
> 2023-10-14 10:30:44.818 ERROR 17204 --- [         task-2]
> .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception
> occurred invoking async method: public void
> com.sixdee.echelon.service.MsisdnManageServices.ApproveNumberPool(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Long)
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
> statement     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible

---

Adding the snap of the error.
Please help us to resolve

By using a jpa query need to update the records in to oracle db from spring boot application.
Below is the jpa qiery

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "update NUMBER_POOL NP set NP.STATUS=:status , NP.CHANGE_DATE=:date where NP.RANGE_ID=:id and NP.STATUS= 15 LIMIT :limit ",nativeQuery = true)
int approveMsisdnRange(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("status") Integer status, @Param("date") Date date,@Param("limit") int limit);
```

Comment: the `limit` part is suspect - is that correct? - please copy the entire query and run it in your SQL client (toad or otherwise) and verify that its syntax is correct

Comment: Oracle does not support the LIMIT clause in the UPDATE statement. You can use the LIMIT clause only in the SELECT statement to limit the number of rows returned by a query. To update a limited number of rows in Oracle, you need to use a subquery with the ROWNUM pseudocolumn.

Comment: @bahmankarami That is incorrect. You cannot use a `LIMIT` clause in any statements (including `SELECT`) as that syntax is not supported. Either filter using `ROWNUM` or, from Oracle 12, use `FETCH FIRST :limit ROWS ONLY`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that comments guys left below the question are fairly enough to get rid the problem. But I still decided write an answer as it could be useful for many people who have just begun diving into Spring.

The JPA, as well as any other superstructure over the native code, just gives us a bit simplifying and minimizes lots of routine. But it won't be able to do anything, that can't be done by itself. So in any case the first step should be to make sure, that you native code is completely correct and can be successfuly executed.

With all of this writing above, think of your goal, then write executable code in pl/sql Developer or whatever, test it, and only then put it into repository's query.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` syntax is not supported in Oracle (in any DML statements, not just `UPDATE`s).

Your query should just be:

```sql
UPDATE NUMBER_POOL
SET   STATUS      = :status,
      CHANGE_DATE = :date
WHERE RANGE_ID    = :id
AND   STATUS      = 15
```

If you only want to update the first few (randomly ordered) rows then use a `MERGE` statement with a `ROWNUM` filter (or, from Oracle 12, `FETCH FIRST :limit ROWS ONLY`):

```sql
MERGE INTO number_pool dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid
  FROM   number_pool
  WHERE  range_id = :id
  AND    status   = 15
  AND    ROWNUM   <= :limit
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET status      = :status,
      change_date = :date
```

or a correlated update:

```sql
UPDATE number_pool
SET   status      = :status,
      change_date = :date
WHERE ROWID IN (
                 SELECT ROWID
                 FROM   number_pool
                 WHERE  range_id = :id
                 AND    status   = 15
                 AND    ROWNUM   <= :limit
               )
```